# See if an account exists in SFDC, otherwise create it?

Tags: informatica

I have an integration from a flat file with a account-identifier. In SFDC, each acct record has a FK with that identifier. Is there a way to lookup to see if the record exists in SF, and if not, create it ?

How would I do it?

Comment: your scenario is not at all clear, you need to use table names, column names, constraint details, data residing into that table and expected output so that people over here can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible at least as a two step process. First, perform a lookup to check all the accounts you will need and create all the missing entries. Then load the data with the second session.